# Getting rid of site created via the developer tools

Tags: rimworld

I was snooping around the dev tools and noticed an option to create a "Debug Arena". I decided to try creating one. I immediately got an error though that it hadn't been setup correctly, but it added a location on the map called "Site".

I realized that I'm on permadeath and didn't know what would happen if I visited it, so I never went near it. It's stuck on my map now though, and also creates an error every time I start the game. See the screenshot for the debug logs, and a picture of the "Site" (with my settlement to the left of it).

[image: Debug log in map]

I've searched all over the dev tools to find an option to delete map sites, but haven't found anything.

How can I remove the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/RimWorld/comments/5ll09m/using_dev_tools_other_methods_to_destroy/) (thanks r/vividflash) on how to do it and decided to document it a little more thoroughly.

---

I ended up editing the save file. My file was found at

```
C:\user\%username%\AppData\LocalLow\Ludeon Studios\RimWorld by Ludeon Studios\Saves
```

Then I found the `.rws` file with my save name, and made a backup copy of it.

I opened the save using Notepad++ as noted in the Reddit post. My save was 11mb, so the built-in Notepad didn't have a chance of opening it.

I searched for "arena" and found *multiple* nodes in the tree that looked like:

```
<li Class="MapParent">
    <def>Debug_Arena</def>
    <ID>386</ID>
    <tile>26840</tile>
    <faction>null</faction>
    <creationGameTicks>17762348</creationGameTicks>
</li>
```

I had accidentally created other weird things on the map as well when I was messing around, and they all seemed to be referred to as "Debug_Arena"s. I deleted them all, loaded up the save, and all the weird map sites had disappeared.